# check if php-clause true or false using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, clause

hey there i have this script´s:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "checkAvailability.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: 'username=' + $(this).data('id'),
    success: function(data) {
            if (result == 1) {
                    $("#select-err").text(data.error ? data.error : "");
            }
            else {
                    $("#select-err").text(data.error ? data.error : "");
            }
    }
});
```

in checkAvailability.php:

```
$availabilityChecker = new AvailabilityChecker($config);

if($availabilityChecker->check_availability($_POST['username'])) {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "is ok"));
    $result = 1;
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "Wrong chose"));
    $result = 0;
}
```

while testing i found out that this is not the correct way to check if a php-clause is true or false, so i need your help...could anyone show me how to check this via jquery? greetings and thanks!

UPDATE:
i changed to:

```
$availabilityChecker = new AvailabilityChecker($config);

if($availabilityChecker->check_availability($_POST['username'])) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

and:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "checkAvailability.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: 'username=' + $(this).data('id'),
    success: function(data){
         if(data == 1){
             $("#select-err").text(data.error ? data.error : "is ok");
         }
         else{
             $("#select-err").text(data.error ? data.error : "not ok");
         }
    }
});
```

it works, BUT:
if data == 1, on my page "1" is displayed, why and how can i fix this?

Comment: And what is wrong with the code you have, why do you think it's not the correct way to do this? There are some things that could be shortened down a bit, but the code in general seems fine to me !

Comment: "while testing i found out that this is not the correct way to check if a php-clause is true or false"

Comment: And why not, why do you assume it's wrong? A if/else condition is just fine, so is echoing JSON when the ajax call has a datatype of JSON, but if you mean the class `AvailabilityChecker`, we have no idea what that looks like and can't help you with that.

Comment: Here's how to do it, add the result to the array you're encoding in the PHP, like this -> `echo json_encode(array("error" => "is ok", "result" => 1));`, and then in the ajax call check it with `if (data.result == 1) {...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
if (result == 1) {
```

do this

```
if (data.result == 1) {
```

inside your success callback javascript file.

Then in your PHP file instead of these:

```
echo json_encode(array("error" => "is ok"));
echo json_encode(array("error" => "Wrong chose"));
```

do these instead:

```
echo json_encode(array("error" => "is ok", "result"=>1));
echo json_encode(array("error" => "Wrong chose", "result"=>0));
```

What I did is I included result as a property in the JSON coming from AJAX call. So instead of only having the error property you also have the result property in the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

in php change to this

```
$availabilityChecker = new AvailabilityChecker($config);

if($availabilityChecker->check_availability($_POST['username'])) {
  echo json_encode(array("error" => "is ok" , "result"=>1));

} else {

  echo json_encode(array("error" => "Wrong chose" , "result"=>0));
}
```

and in jquery

check as

```
if(data.result==1){
  // do the same
}else{
}
```

Comment: but i need to check because of following functions, so could you help me to check if php-clause is true OR false?

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo `json_encode(array("error" => "is ok"));` in php in `if-else` statement, just echo result in both cases.
In you ajax it on `success` callback, it will return everything that is on ur php page i.e. `result` which may be 1 or 0. SO check if `data==1` or `data==0` instead of `result`.

Comment: i am not really sure what you mean? could just show an example? greetings!

Comment: i mean just use echo "1" or "0" in php and according to that modify $("#select-err").txt();

Comment: but i am using json as datatype, so how to use echo?

Comment: @user2999787 The `$result=…` line is absolutely pointless in the PHP script. It doesn't get returned anywhere. The JavaScript won't see it.

Comment: When you're using an ajax call that expects json to be returned, you'll fail miserably when returning just a boolean

Comment: @user2999787 use echo "1"; and echo "0"; in php. and in ajax check whether data=="1" or data=="0" and do operation on select-err accordingly

Comment: @i_m_optional - you're not really getting it, you'll have a parse error in the ajax call because the returned value isn't json, so there will be no data to check.

Comment: no this will work, i have used it several times and it work fine

Comment: i updated, could you take a look and tell me why the "echo" gets displayed?

Comment: are ur ajax and php are on same file?

Comment: so all of ur page data is erased and only "1" is displayed? or just select-err section is displaying 1. If it is the second one, you may change  $("#select-err").text(data.error ? data.error : "is ok"); to  $("#select-err").text("is ok"); this only. and also use data.trim() before comparing data.

Comment: just select-err section is displaying 1